# Sandbox module doesn't show any download link

Tags: community-official-site

I've recently developed a module, Drupal to SugarCRM Lea', and decided to contribute to community. I've followed every steps on drupal.org to do so. I have managed to upload all my code to the sandbox, but my project page is not showing any download links for my module.

- [Repository](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/sandbox-dipesh_patel-2398649)
- [Module page](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/dipesh_patel/2398649)

What did I forget to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sandbox projects may not have releases.

There is a "Has project releases" checkbox, in the "Releases" vertical tab when you edit your sandbox, but it will be automatically cleared.

Thus it is not possible, but if you wish, you can [apply for full project access](https://www.drupal.org/node/1011698).